# Is it possible to grow an indoor tea plant?

Tags: indoors, containers, tea

It is at all possible to grow tea plants, particularly something like [Camellia sinensis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sinensis), not herbal teas, indoors with special lighting?  Specifically, I'm not taking about starting tea seedlings and the transplanting outside, but solely growing the plant indoors (from seed to mature plant).

I live in North Dakota (hardiness zone 4), where I am far away from ever seeing a tea plantation outside my window, so (to the best of my knowledge) there isn't any way I would be able to plant tea outside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in a pot you can bring it outdoors when it is warm and bring it indoors while it is cold. Tea is a zone 6 plant so it is relatively hardy and durable. It should survive your winter inside similar to how you would overwinter other plants.

Comment: Is it really a zone six plant? I asked a question about their hardiness and didn't get an answer. Maybe you could answer it.

Comment: @jmusser's related question [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3211/705).