# Indoor small tea plant and Vinca care

Tags: indoors, tea

Sorry to make a **double question** but I'm totally new.
I live in an apartment, and I really want to have a tea plant, but unfortunately I have no space for huge plants. In [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/is-it-possible-to-grow-an-indoor-tea-plant) I read I can have certain tea plants indoors, but which is **the smallest** I can get?

And, apart from this subject, I bought a **Vinca pot**, and I really want it to be ok indoors. I don't over-irrigate it and I water-spray the leaves, do I have to do anything special to keep it okay? and, is it okay if the flowers fall in few days?

Answer (score 1):

Camellia sinensis varieties grown outdoors in an appropriate zone will reach about 15 feet, but indoors in a pot, around 6 feet.  However, all need to be stood outside during the summer months, so if you cannot do this, you're unlikely to have much success with it. Even if you can stand it outside, its not easy to grow indoors - its a bit of a prima donna, reacting badly to the slightest changes in temperature or draughts.

As for the Vinca, do you mean Vinca major or minor, or Catharansus rosea, the Madagascan periwinkle, previously called Vinca, and still commonly called by that name? If you're not sure, the link below should help you decide:

http://www.ehow.com/info_8019153_difference-vinca-flower-vinca-vine.html

The next link is somewhat confusing - it talks about growing vinca 'vines' indoors, but the vinca its referring to is actually Catharansus roseus, not V. major or V. minor. I know this because V. major/minor do not require warm temperatures, they're hardy, sprawling, messy growing, evergreen perennials which grow outdoors and produce blue flowers in early spring, then stop flowering until the following spring. That said, the article gives instructions as to how to grow Catharansus indoors as a houseplant, so its useful for that

http://www.ehow.com/how_12124991_make-vinca-vines-grow-indoors.html

Comment: oh... too bad, I won't be able to have any tea plant, then.

Comment: anyway I thought it was a minor vinca, but now I read this I think it might be Catharansus roseus, so thanks a lot for the link

Comment: OK So I't getting worse. also another of my flower plants is getting worse I'm worried. I asked at the local greenhouse how to make it better and did everything they said but it's not working.

Comment: @Paula - if you're happy with the above answer, please accept it, otherwise its still open.